# Yii2 render frontend view from backend controller

Tags: php, yii2

My task is simple. I have to render frontend view from backend controller. What i've done so far is to create `urlManagerFrontendView` path in my `main.php`:

```
'urlManagerFrontendView' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
    'baseUrl' => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/frontend/view/',
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
],
```

This is how i am trying to render it(from the backend):

```
return $this->render(''.Yii::$app->urlManagerFrontendView->baseUrl.'page/product', [
            'model' => $product,
            'product_rel' => $product_rel,
            'thispage' => $thispage,
        ]);
```

But what i get is an error:

```
The view file does not exist: /home/projects/tashev-online/htdocs/backend/views/home/projects/tashev-online/htdocs/frontend/viewpage/product.php
```

Obviously i didn't create it right :) So can you guys help my with my path? What is the right way to reach the frontend? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to do anything with UrlManager in this case. Simply call the view using relative path (like this or similar):

```
return $this->render('../../../frontend/views/page/product', ...
```

Comment: Thank you! That decides one of the problems :D

Answer (score 0):

Render one module to anther module

return $this->redirect(\Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(array("master/students/view", 'ccid'=> $std->ccid,'admission_number'=>$std->admission_number)));